# Ratio of two ideal sets

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be the cardinality of the set of all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $B$ be the cardinality of the set of all principal ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$
What can we say about this ratio $\frac{A}{B}$? Is it finite?

Comment: $A$ and  $B$ are both infinite cardinals, so there's no such thing as $A/B$.

Comment: Ok, $\mathbb{Z}$ and $2\mathbb{Z}$  both are infinite but their ration is 1/2. We know class group is always finite. Can we give group structure on set of fractional ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$

Comment: Huh? $\Bbb Z$ and $2\Bbb Z$ are not cardinals.

Comment: And, not that it has anything to do with division of cardinals, but there _is_ such a thing as $\Bbb Z/(2\Bbb Z)$. It has cardinalilty $2$. How you're going to get $\Bbb Z/(2\Bbb Z)=1/2$ escapes me...

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as the ratio of two infinite cardinals. If $A$ and $B$ are infinite cardinals, as in the OP, then $A/B$ is undefined.

Of course I can't prove mathematically that a  definition does not exist. But I *can* explain why nobody ever got around to giving that definition: If, say, $A$ and $B$ are real numbers and $B\ne0$ then $A/B$ is defined to be the unique solution to $Bx=A$. And that definition simply doesn't work for infinite cardinals.

For example, $\aleph_0=\aleph_02=\aleph_0\aleph_0$, so if we try to use that definition here we get $$2=\aleph_0/\aleph_0=\aleph_0.$$